# To substitute lsb value of rgb image with character

Tags: matlab, image-processing, steganography

I want to substitute LSB of rgb image with character. I have done it for gray sacle image using bitset and bitget. Can I use same logic for rgb image?
Here is part of code which I have used:

stego=zeros(size(img))
stego=bitset(stego,1,lsp)

Where img is cover image and lsp is binary message. I have then merge bitplanes by:

stego=bitset(stego,2,bitget(img,2))

Up to 8th plane to get the strgo image.
How can I build the same logic for RGB image? Please guide me.

Comment: You'll likely have to do this with each channel (R,G, B) separately.

Comment: How? can you please elaborate?

Comment: for example for 24bit pixel format your color could be in hex `0x00RRGGBB` so **LSB** bits available for this are `0,8,16` not just `0`. As we do not know how your image is stored we can only speculate you need to add more info. Also sometimes green channel is ignored for this due to higher human perception in this range.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you now  please help me. Please guide me asap.

Comment: There are myriads of ways of embedding bits in RGB images, but here are the 4 most frequent ones. 1, choose a plane and embed only there (same as in grayscale); 2, embed in one colour like in (1), but if you run out of pixels, start embedding in a second colour plane; 3, for each pixel, embed one bit in R, one bit in G and one bit in B; 4, for each pixel embed three bits in R, three bits in G and two bits in B. Which one do you want? I also find extending the logic in all of them straightforward if you can embed in a grayscale, so you also want to clarify what you're struggling with.

Comment: Actually I am struggling with how to do embedding in rgb, in the way it will be reliable. @Reti43 As you said, please guide me with how to implement your 3rd, 4th way. It will helpfull if you give example.

Comment: Can anyone please explain me how to do the embedding as I mentioned in the question? Please help me out. I am really confused. I have gone through various questions and answers based on the same topic stegno but not reached to satisfied answer.